# Impute categorical missing values in scikit-learn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, imputation

I've got pandas data with some columns of text type. There are some NaN values along with these text columns. What I'm trying to do is to impute those NaN's by `sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer` (replacing NaN by the most frequent value). The problem is in implementation.
Suppose there is a Pandas dataframe df with 30 columns, 10 of which are of categorical nature.
Once I run:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imp = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='most_frequent', axis=0)
imp.fit(df)
```

Python generates an `error: 'could not convert string to float: 'run1''`, where 'run1' is an ordinary (non-missing) value from the first column with categorical data.

Any help would be very welcome

Comment: `Imputer` works on numbers, not strings. Convert to numbers, then impute, then convert back.

Comment: Are there any suitable ways to automate it via scikit-learn?

Comment: Why would it not allow categorical vars for most_frequent strategy? strange.

Comment: You can now use `from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer` and then `imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='most_frequent')`

Answer (score 112, accepted):

To use mean values for numeric columns and the most frequent value for non-numeric columns you could do something like this. You could further distinguish between integers and floats. I guess it might make sense to use the median for integer columns instead.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin

class DataFrameImputer(TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self):
        """Impute missing values.

        Columns of dtype object are imputed with the most frequent value 
        in column.

        Columns of other types are imputed with mean of column.

        """
    def fit(self, X, y=None):

        self.fill = pd.Series([X[c].value_counts().index[0]
            if X[c].dtype == np.dtype('O') else X[c].mean() for c in X],
            index=X.columns)

        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        return X.fillna(self.fill)

data = [
    ['a', 1, 2],
    ['b', 1, 1],
    ['b', 2, 2],
    [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]
]

X = pd.DataFrame(data)
xt = DataFrameImputer().fit_transform(X)

print('before...')
print(X)
print('after...')
print(xt)
```

which prints,

```
before...
     0   1   2
0    a   1   2
1    b   1   1
2    b   2   2
3  NaN NaN NaN
after...
   0         1         2
0  a  1.000000  2.000000
1  b  1.000000  1.000000
2  b  2.000000  2.000000
3  b  1.333333  1.666667
```

Comment: Great job. I'm going to use your snippet in [xtoy](https://github.com/kootenpv/xtoy) :) If you have any further suggestions, I'd be happy to hear them.

Comment: This is great, but if any column has all NaN values, it won't work. These all NaN columns should be dropped from the DF.

Comment: Great :) I'm going to use this but change it a bit so that it used mean for floats, median for ints, mode for strings

Comment: `DataFrameImputer() does not have get_params() attribute` error when used in GridSearchCV. The fix is to inherit from `sklearn.base.BaseEstimator` also.

Comment: @GauthamKumaran Pass BaseEstimator also in the above class. It will work

Comment: Why did you use fit_transform? I'm confused as you never defined any fit_transform function within your class method.

Comment: @mamun The `fit_transform` method is provided by the [TransfomerMixin](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.base.TransformerMixin.html) class.

Comment: This should be accepted as an additional feature in sklearn's imputer class.

Answer (score 15):

You can use `sklearn_pandas.CategoricalImputer` for the categorical columns. Details:

First, (from the book Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn and TensorFlow) you can have subpipelines for numerical and string/categorical features, where each subpipeline's first transformer is a selector that takes a list of column names (and the `full_pipeline.fit_transform()` takes a pandas DataFrame):

```
class DataFrameSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, attribute_names):
        self.attribute_names = attribute_names
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self, X):
        return X[self.attribute_names].values
```

You can then combine these sub pipelines with `sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion`, for example:

```
full_pipeline = FeatureUnion(transformer_list=[
    ("num_pipeline", num_pipeline),
    ("cat_pipeline", cat_pipeline)
])
```

Now, in the `num_pipeline` you can simply use `sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer()`, but in the `cat_pipline`, you can use `CategoricalImputer()` from the `sklearn_pandas` package.

**note:** `sklearn-pandas` package can be installed with `pip install sklearn-pandas`, but it is imported as `import sklearn_pandas`

Answer (score 8):

There is a package `sklearn-pandas` which has option for imputation for categorical variable
https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/sklearn-pandas#categoricalimputer

```
>>> from sklearn_pandas import CategoricalImputer
>>> data = np.array(['a', 'b', 'b', np.nan], dtype=object)
>>> imputer = CategoricalImputer()
>>> imputer.fit_transform(data)
array(['a', 'b', 'b', 'b'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: I back this answer; the official sklearn-pandas documentation on the pypi website mentions this: "CategoricalImputer
Since the scikit-learn Imputer transformer currently only works with numbers, sklearn-pandas provides an equivalent helper transformer that do work with strings, substituting null values with the most frequent value in that column."https://pypi.org/project/sklearn-pandas/1.5.0/

Comment: This was [removed](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/sklearn-pandas#200-2020-08-01) from the package.

Answer (score 6):

- strategy = 'most_frequent' can be used only with quantitative feature, not with qualitative.  This custom impuer can be used for both qualitative and quantitative. Also with scikit learn imputer either we can use it for whole data frame(if all features are quantitative) or we can use 'for loop' with list of similar type of features/columns(see the below example). But custom imputer can be used with any combinations.

  ```
      from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
      impute = Imputer(strategy='mean')
      for cols in ['quantitative_column', 'quant']:  # here both are quantitative features.
            xx[cols] = impute.fit_transform(xx[[cols]])
  ```
- Custom Imputer :

  ```
     from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
     from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin

     class CustomImputer(TransformerMixin):
           def __init__(self, cols=None, strategy='mean'):
                 self.cols = cols
                 self.strategy = strategy

           def transform(self, df):
                 X = df.copy()
                 impute = Imputer(strategy=self.strategy)
                 if self.cols == None:
                        self.cols = list(X.columns)
                 for col in self.cols:
                        if X[col].dtype == np.dtype('O') : 
                               X[col].fillna(X[col].value_counts().index[0], inplace=True)
                        else : X[col] = impute.fit_transform(X[[col]])

                 return X

           def fit(self, *_):
                 return self
  ```
- Dataframe:

  ```
        X = pd.DataFrame({'city':['tokyo', np.NaN, 'london', 'seattle', 'san 
                                   francisco', 'tokyo'], 
            'boolean':['yes', 'no', np.NaN, 'no', 'no', 'yes'], 
            'ordinal_column':['somewhat like', 'like', 'somewhat like', 'like', 
                              'somewhat like', 'dislike'], 
            'quantitative_column':[1, 11, -.5, 10, np.NaN, 20]})


              city              boolean   ordinal_column  quantitative_column
          0   tokyo             yes       somewhat like   1.0
          1   NaN               no        like            11.0
          2   london            NaN       somewhat like   -0.5
          3   seattle           no        like            10.0
          4   san francisco     no        somewhat like   NaN
          5   tokyo             yes       dislike         20.0
  ```
- 1) Can be used with list of similar type of features.

  ```
   cci = CustomImputer(cols=['city', 'boolean']) # here default strategy = mean
   cci.fit_transform(X)
  ```
- can be used with strategy = median

  ```
   sd = CustomImputer(['quantitative_column'], strategy = 'median')
   sd.fit_transform(X)
  ```
- 3) Can be used with whole data frame, it will use default mean(or we can also change it with median. for qualitative features it uses strategy = 'most_frequent' and for quantitative mean/median.

  ```
   call = CustomImputer()
   call.fit_transform(X)
  ```

Answer (score 4):

Copying and modifying sveitser's answer, I made an imputer for a pandas.Series object

```
import numpy
import pandas 

from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin

class SeriesImputer(TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self):
        """Impute missing values.

        If the Series is of dtype Object, then impute with the most frequent object.
        If the Series is not of dtype Object, then impute with the mean.  

        """
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        if   X.dtype == numpy.dtype('O'): self.fill = X.value_counts().index[0]
        else                            : self.fill = X.mean()
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
       return X.fillna(self.fill)
```

To use it you would do:

```
# Make a series
s1 = pandas.Series(['k', 'i', 't', 't', 'e', numpy.NaN])


a  = SeriesImputer()   # Initialize the imputer
a.fit(s1)              # Fit the imputer
s2 = a.transform(s1)   # Get a new series
```

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by the answers here and for the want of a goto Imputer for all use-cases I ended up writing this. It supports four strategies for imputation `mean, mode, median, fill` works on both `pd.DataFrame` and `Pd.Series`.

`mean` and `median` works only for numeric data, `mode` and `fill` works for both numeric and categorical data.

```
class CustomImputer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, strategy='mean',filler='NA'):
       self.strategy = strategy
       self.fill = filler

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
       if self.strategy in ['mean','median']:
           if not all(X.dtypes == np.number):
               raise ValueError('dtypes mismatch np.number dtype is \
                                 required for '+ self.strategy)
       if self.strategy == 'mean':
           self.fill = X.mean()
       elif self.strategy == 'median':
           self.fill = X.median()
       elif self.strategy == 'mode':
           self.fill = X.mode().iloc[0]
       elif self.strategy == 'fill':
           if type(self.fill) is list and type(X) is pd.DataFrame:
               self.fill = dict([(cname, v) for cname,v in zip(X.columns, self.fill)])
       return self

   def transform(self, X, y=None):
       return X.fillna(self.fill)
```

usage

```
>> df   
    MasVnrArea  FireplaceQu
Id  
1   196.0   NaN
974 196.0   NaN
21  380.0   Gd
5   350.0   TA
651 NaN     Gd


>> CustomImputer(strategy='mode').fit_transform(df)
MasVnrArea  FireplaceQu
Id      
1   196.0   Gd
974 196.0   Gd
21  380.0   Gd
5   350.0   TA
651 196.0   Gd

>> CustomImputer(strategy='fill', filler=[0, 'NA']).fit_transform(df)
MasVnrArea  FireplaceQu
Id      
1   196.0   NA
974 196.0   NA
21  380.0   Gd
5   350.0   TA
651 0.0     Gd
```

Answer (score 2):

Missforest can be used for the imputation of missing values in categorical variable along with the other categorical features. It works in an iterative way similar to IterativeImputer taking random forest as a base model.

Following is the code to label encode the features along with the target variable, fitting model to impute nan values, and encoding the features back

```
import sklearn.neighbors._base
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import sys
sys.modules['sklearn.neighbors.base'] = sklearn.neighbors._base
from missingpy import MissForest

def label_encoding(df, columns):
    """
    Label encodes the set of the features to be used for imputation
    Args:
        df: data frame (processed data)
        columns: list (features to be encoded)
    Returns: dictionary
    """
    encoders = dict()
    for col_name in columns:
        series = df[col_name]
        label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
        df[col_name] = pd.Series(
            label_encoder.fit_transform(series[series.notnull()]),
            index=series[series.notnull()].index
        )
        encoders[col_name] = label_encoder
    return encoders

# adding to be imputed global category along with features
features = ['feature_1', 'feature_2', 'target_variable']
# label encoding features
encoders = label_encoding(data, features)
# categorical imputation using random forest 
# parameters can be tuned accordingly
imp_cat = MissForest(n_estimators=50, max_depth=80)
data[features] = imp_cat.fit_transform(data[features], cat_vars=[0, 1, 2])
# decoding features
for variable in features:
    data[variable] = encoders[variable].inverse_transform(data[variable].astype(int))
```

Answer (score 1):

This code fills in a series with the most frequent category:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create fake data 
m = pd.Series(list('abca'))
m.iloc[1] = np.nan #artificially introduce nan

print('m = ')
print(m)

#make dummy variables, count and sort descending:
most_common = pd.get_dummies(m).sum().sort_values(ascending=False).index[0] 

def replace_most_common(x):
    if pd.isnull(x):
        return most_common
    else:
        return x

new_m = m.map(replace_most_common) #apply function to original data

print('new_m = ')
print(new_m)
```

Outputs:

```
m =
0      a
1    NaN
2      c
3      a
dtype: object

new_m =
0    a
1    a
2    c
3    a
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer instead of Imputer can easily resolve this, which can handle categorical variable.

As per the Sklearn documentation:
If “most_frequent”, then replace missing using the most frequent value along each column. Can be used with strings or numeric data.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html

```
impute_size=SimpleImputer(strategy="most_frequent") 
data['Outlet_Size']=impute_size.transform(data[['Outlet_Size']])
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar.  Modify `Imputer` for `strategy='most_frequent'`:

```
class GeneralImputer(Imputer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Imputer.__init__(self, **kwargs)

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        if self.strategy == 'most_frequent':
            self.fills = pd.DataFrame(X).mode(axis=0).squeeze()
            self.statistics_ = self.fills.values
            return self
        else:
            return Imputer.fit(self, X, y=y)

    def transform(self, X):
        if hasattr(self, 'fills'):
            return pd.DataFrame(X).fillna(self.fills).values.astype(str)
        else:
            return Imputer.transform(self, X)
```

where `pandas.DataFrame.mode()` finds the most frequent value for each column and then `pandas.DataFrame.fillna()` fills missing values with these.  Other `strategy` values are still handled the same way by `Imputer`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
replace = df.<yourcolumn>.value_counts().argmax()

df['<yourcolumn>'].fillna(replace, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my attempt at multiple imputation based on @Gautham Kumaran ideas. It will use mode, "most frequent", for categorical variables replacement and then do multiple imputation via regression for numeric variables

```
# mising values imputation
from sklearn.experimental import enable_iterative_imputer
from sklearn.impute import IterativeImputer
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

# class for missing data imputation
# =============================================================
class MVImputer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, random_state=None, filler='NA'):
        self.random_state = random_state
        self.fill = filler
        
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        categorical_dtypes = ['object', 'category', 'bool']
        numerical_dtypes = ['float', 'int']
        for col in X.columns:
            if X[col].dtype.name in categorical_dtypes:
                self.fill = X.mode().iloc[0]
            elif X[col].dtype.name in numerical_dtypes:
                min_val = X[col].min(axis=0)
                max_val = X[col].max(axis=0)
                imputer = (IterativeImputer(max_iter=10,
                                            random_state=self.random_state,
                                            min_value=min_val, 
                                            max_value=max_val))
                self.fill = imputer.fit(X)
        return self
    
    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        return X.fillna(self.fill)

# call for single imputed dataframe
imp = MVImputer()
imp.fit_transform(df) 

# multiple imputed dict of dataframes
mvi = {}
for i in range(3):
    imp = Imputer()
    mvi[i] = imp.fit_transform(df)
```