# RandomForestClassifier for multiclass classification Spark 2.x

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, random-forest, multiclass-classification

I'm trying to use random forest for a multiclass classification using spark 2.1.1

After defining my pipeline as usual, it's failing during indexing stage.

I have a dataframe with many string type columns. I have created a StringIndexer for each of them.

I am creating a Pipeline by chaining the StringIndexers with VectorAssembler and finally a RandomForestClassifier following by a label converter.

I've checked all my columns with `distinct().count()` to make sure I do not have too many categories and so on...

After some debugging, I understand that whenever I started the indexing of some of the columns I get the following errors...
 When calling:

```
  val indexer = udf { label: String =>
  if (labelToIndex.contains(label)) {
    labelToIndex(label)
  } else {
    throw new SparkException(s"Unseen label: $label.")
  }
}

Error evaluating methog: 'labelToIndex'
Error evaluating methog: 'labels'
```

Then inside the transformation, there is this error when defining the metadata:

> Error evaluating method: org$apache$spark$ml$feature$StringIndexerModel$$labelToIndex
>   Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate org.apache.spark.sql.types.Metadata.toString()

This is happening because I have null on some columns that I'm indexing.

I could reproduce the error with the following example.

```
val df = spark.createDataFrame(
  Seq(("asd2s","1e1e",1.1,0), ("asd2s","1e1e",0.1,0), 
      (null,"1e3e",1.2,0), ("bd34t","1e1e",5.1,1), 
      ("asd2s","1e3e",0.2,0), ("bd34t","1e2e",4.3,1))
).toDF("x0","x1","x2","x3")

val indexer = new 
StringIndexer().setInputCol("x0").setOutputCol("x0idx")

indexer.fit(df).transform(df).show

// java.lang.NullPointerException
```

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11569

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.1/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/StringIndexer.scala

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spark.ml StringIndexer throws 'Unseen label' on fit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35224675/spark-ml-stringindexer-throws-unseen-label-on-fit)

Comment: At first, I was thinking that the problem could be because of something similar to the ones mentioned there...but it's not.

Comment: The solution present [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33574807/apache-spark-throws-nullpointerexception-when-encountering-missing-feature) can be used, and on the [Spark 2.2.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11569), the issue is fixed upstream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution present [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33574807/apache-spark-throws-nullpointerexception-when-encountering-missing-feature) can be used, and on the [Spark 2.2.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11569), the issue is fixed upstream.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
DataFrame.na.fill(Map("colName1", val1), ("colName2", val2),..))

Where:

DataFrame - DataFrame Object ; "colName" - name of the column & val - value for replacing nulls if any found in column "colName".

Use feature transformations, after filling all nulls.

You can check for number of nulls in all columns of  as:

for ( column <- DataFrame.columns ) {
DataFrame.filter(DataFrame(column) === null || DataFrame(column).isNull || DataFrame(column).isNan).count()

}

OR

DataFrame.count() will give you total number of rows in DataFrame. Then number of nulls can be judged by DataFrame.describe()