# Imputer with different types of values

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

Does the Imputer in sklearn can deal with different types of data?

For example string and numbers are both represented as `?`,
when applying the Imputer it works with only one strategy.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, [Imputer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html) only works with numeric data types, and imputes values that are `nan`, not the string `?`.

To be able to impute string values, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25562948/356729).